# Which kinds of death are instantaneous?

Tags: borderlands-2

Some deaths cause the Vault Hunter's body to become a ragdoll and sort-of digitizes them (e.g., bleeding out in Fight For Your Life mode). Other deaths instantly send you into the travel vortex (e.g., being run over by a vehicle while in Fight For Your Life mode). A Mechromancer does not lose Anarchy stacks upon death if the death is instantaneous, so I'd like to know which kinds of death are which.

If it's shorter to list which kinds of death cause ragdoll + digitization, list that instead.

Comment: Warning, long comment...  I always felt that it was strange that being ran over in FFYL brought you straight to the vortex.  It might just be an exception.  However, I also I found this on the[Bordlands wiki](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Anarchy_(skill)): "If Gaige falls off the map, she may or may not lose her stacks of Anarchy. If the camera switches to third person as one falls off the map, the stacks will be reset. Otherwise they will be retained."     It sounds almost like "No 3rd person camera during death = You keep anarchy stacks."  Not sure when that happens though.

Comment: Just to be clear, does being ran-over in FFYL mode not reset your acarchy?

Comment: Pretty sure yes.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently started a Gaige playthrough myself, and did a little ingame research.

As @PawnInGameOfLife already pointed out, you may not always lose your stacks of Anarchy when you fall off the map.

You DO lose them when: you fall OFF a map (meaning OutOfBounds or jumping off a cliff)

You DO NOT lose them when: you get shot from one of the turrets, where you could otherwise walk off the map into the distance.

The same goes for being run over by a car. You usually go into fight for your life first. If you die then, you will lose them.

An exception to that rule is, if you get run over by the caravan in The Dust. This one also kills you instantly without entering FFYL, therefore not losing you your stacks.